# MSSQL Simple Update Query: UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD = 1 WHERE FIELD = 2

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to perform a simple update query in MS SQL.
In mysql I would issue this:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD = 1 WHERE FIELD = 2
```

I am getting an error when I try this in MS visual studio.  Please any help with this.

The error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. Statement has been terminated.

Thanks.

Comment: Subquery returned more than 1 value.  This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.  Statement has been terminated.

Comment: yeah Code + error msg and details would be necessary to solve this problem

Comment: This doesnt sound right. Did you try to execute the query directly from SQL Management Studio. Can you post the exact query that you are firing from visual studio?

Comment: That error message does not come from the UPDATE. So add all relevant data and code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the limited information to hand, I suspect you have an update trigger on TABLE which is coded to expect a single row being in the `inserted` or `deleted` tables.

Comment: You beat me by a 12 seconds, so I upvoted you and will delete mine.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I forgot about the trigger.